# environment agnostic ARM template parameter file

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a (simplified) ARM template for an Storage Account deployment:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":{
    "env_storage_name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources":[
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name":"[parameters('env_storage_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

This template uses the associated parameter file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env_storage_name": {
            "value": "<env>-storage_name"
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to deploy this template using Powershell by:

```
az deployment group create --name "someDeploymentName" --resource-group "myRG" --template-file "pathToTemplate.json" --parameters "pathToParameters.json"
```

I have googled quite a bit, but so far I havent found a way to dynamically replace the **env** substring in my parameter with e.g. "dev", "tst", "acc", "prd".What I want to do is effectively use the same Powershell command an "pipe in" the environment. I have tried to play around with variables, but so far I haven't managed to get it done.

Is that possible? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that solves my problem is, to use variables to concatinate my relevant resource names etc from parameters. It took me a while understand the possibilities that ARM gives you here.

I am now using this template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "subscription": {
        "type": "string"
      },
        "env": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
        "storage_name":  "[concat(parameters('subscription'),'-',parameters('env'),'-storage_account_name')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
          "name":"[variables('storage_name')]",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01"
      }
    ]
}
```

and feed it with this parameter file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
            "subscription": {
            "value": "mySub"
        },
            "env": {
            "value": "dev"
        }
    }
}
```

So the only thing that I have to do is change the "env" parameter in the parameter file.

This does NOT give me the possibility to push a button and all four environments are created sequentially, but that is not part of the requirements atm. I still have to manually change "dev" to "tst" for example and rerun my PowerShell script, but that is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above requirement we have created the below arm template to create the storage account & tested in our environment it is working fine.

```
{
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
   "parameters":{
      "env_storage":{
         "type":"string",
         "allowedValues":[
            "dev",
            "test",
            "acc",
            "prd"
         ]
      },
      "storageName":{
         "type":"string"
      }
   },
   "functions":[
      
   ],
   "variables":{
      
   },
   "resources":[
      {
         "type":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
         "apiVersion":"2021-04-01",
         "name":"[concat(parameters('env_storage'),parameters('storageName'))]",
         "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
         "kind":"StorageV2",
         "sku":{
            "name":"Premium_LRS",
            "tier":"Premium"
         }
      }
   ],
   "outputs":{
      
   }
}
```

Instead of creating a separate file for parameters.json you can pass the parameters directly in the **az deployment group cmdlet**  as shown in below format.

for PowerShell :

```
$paramObject = @{ <list of parameters that declared in the deploymenttemplate.json>
    'env_storage' = '<env_value>'
    'storageName'  = '<account Name>'
}

$parameters = @{
    'Name'                  = '<deploymentName>'
    'ResourceGroupName'     = '<resourcegroupname>'
    'TemplateFile'          = '<deploymenttemplate.json'
    'TemplateParameterObject'  = $paramObject
    'Verbose'               = $true
}

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
```

if you are using the Bash you can use the below format to pass the parameters during the az deployment group create cmdlet

```
 $params = '{ \"env_storage\": {\"value\":\"<env_value>\"}, \"<storageName>\": {\"value\":\"<stroageaccountName\"} }'
        
 az deployment group create  --resource-group <resourcegrpName> --template-file <deploymenttemplate.json>  --parameters $params
```

Here is the reference documentation to know more information about how to [pass parameters in azure deployment group cli cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your input @VenkatesDodda-MT. I haven't been able to get your solution to work for my case, probably due to my limited PowerShell experience. But I have found a workaround which I'll post below.